# C++ Referencing an Object from a global static function

Tags: c++

I have a globally declared static function that needs to reference an object, but when I do so, I get an "undeclared identifier" error.

Here is a sample of my code

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Trigger.h"

using namespace std;

namespace Gamma_Globals
{
    static vector<void*> gvTriggers;
}

static LPARAM CALLBACK ProgramWndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static LPARAM CALLBACK ProgramWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Gamma_Globals::gvTriggers.size(); i++)
            {
                Trigger t = Gamma_Globals::gvTriggers[i];
            }
        }
    default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The issue comes in the WM_KEYUP case, when I tried to set "Trigger t", I get the error "'Trigger' : undeclared identifier." What can I do to reference the Trigger object from ProgramWndProc?

Thanks!

---

As requested, here is a copy of Trigger.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Noun.h"
#include "TermFactory.h"
#include "Globals.h"

using namespace std;

class Trigger
{
public:
    enum   TRIGGER_TYPE {NONE, ONKEYPRESS, ONMOUSEPRESS};

    Trigger(void*);
    Trigger(LPTSTR trigger, LPTSTR action, Gamma_Globals::TRIGGER_TIME);
    ~Trigger(void);

    VOID Perform();

    TRIGGER_TYPE GetType();

private:
    LPTSTR        lpCondition;
    LPTSTR        lpAction;
    Gamma_Globals::TRIGGER_TIME triggerTime;
    vector<Noun*> vNouns;
    TRIGGER_TYPE  triggerType;

    VOID LoadAction(LPTSTR Action);
    HRESULT LoadCondition(LPTSTR Condition);
};
```

Comment: I updated the post with a copy of Trigger.h

Comment: `#pragma once` in your `cpp` file looks very suspicious

Comment: As a side note, you `WM_KEYUP` has no beak. As for it not being declared, could there be anything left over from `Noun`, `TermFactory`, or `Globals` carrying on into `Trigger`?

Comment: Globals.h is the first file listed. Essentially Trigger needs to use TRIGGER_TIME declared in Globals.h and Globals.h needs to use Trigger declared in Trigger.h

Comment: I agree, I don't like executing code in Globals.h so far that seems to be the only way I can get things to kinda work, but I'll see if I can't fix that somehow.

Comment: This cyclic dependency is bad and will create a lot of problems. Decide which component should depend on which other component.

Comment: Thank you Hrishi, I will see what I can do there as well, as I work on refactoring this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger.h includes globals.h. globals.h inturn includes trigger.h. So while compiling globals.h, the compiler has not seen Class Trigger.

Ideally, there should not be any cyclic dependency in your code. Either trigger.h will depend on globals.h or the opposite not both.

To compile this, you can create global.cpp and put the function definition in there. Note that this will not break the cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 0):

you try to assign a void* to t which is of type Trigger.

since the ctor of Trigger accepts a void* try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Gamma_Globals::gvTriggers.size(); i++)
{
    Trigger t( Gamma_Globals::gvTriggers[i] );
}
```